# Docker-volume binded to an other directory but files are cloned into /var/lib/docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a named volume with my docker-compose file and setup a 'bind' to a local directory, but the files are written in my custom directory and the default docker directory for volumes /var/lib/docker/....

How can i make docker write only on my custom directory ?

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

services:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    app:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        image: php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            - 8090:80
        volumes:
            - app_files_data:/app/files

volumes:
    app_files_data:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
          type: 'none'
          o: 'bind'
          device: '/home/myapp/files'
```

The docker volume inspect

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-08-14T09:47:29Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "php",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "app_files_data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_app_files_data/_data",
        "Name": "php_app_files_data",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/home/myapp/files",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using `app_files_data:/app/files` and the `volumes` sectiony ou use a `named volume` therefor the location is in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` you may change the compose to :

```
version: '3.7'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

services:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    app:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        image: php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            - 8090:80
        volumes:
            - /path/to/app_files_data:/app/files
```

not that I removed the `volumes` section

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: I have one other question @Linpy how do i update the config to not use the volume anymore ? I edited the docker-compose and upped the containers again but files are still written inside the volume.

Comment: you need to remove the containers with `rm` or update them with `--force-recreate`